# How to Deal with String/Date Attributes in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, date, http

Which strategy do you guys use to deal with date attributes on your models which comes from json response on http requests ?

The Date attributes comes in string format and it troubles me when i'm using date components(like a Datepicker).

So, to fix this, usually I convert the String attribute into a date, like this:

```
person.birthday = new Date(person.birthday);
```

But it seems to be bad code. Besides, everytime I create a new date attribute I have to repeat the code above.

How do you guys deal with this situation ?

Comment: If i'll be doing date arithmetic, I convert to a Date object. If I only need to display it, I keep it as a formatted string, which uses fewer resources.

Comment: I don't see another way or use moment but instead of new Date(myStringDate) you have moment(myStringDate)... I agree with @BeetleJuice, when you just need to display the date keep the string

Comment: Unfortunately it's an input / output attribute. .. so need this in a date type. ../=

Comment: BeetleJuice ... do you always convert your data attributes manually?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found is to deal with dates as Timestamps.

This means you store a number, and when you request it, all you have to do is to make a

```
let d = new Date(myTS);
```

You can find some problems to that, such as the timezone depending on the client.

Otherwise, you can use Moment, which is made to deal with this kind of problem.

Comment: Still .. it does not seems to be DRYable

Comment: Sorry, what does DRYable means ?

Comment: Dont Repeat Yourself 
It seems that convert every date attributes is too hard and dont folow DRY principle